# Writing a function to give an interval where the values are greater than a certain number

Tags: r

I'm trying to write a function where I find the number of times the value in a data frame is above a certain number x (in this case, 3). Basically, the data start from 1.0, increase, then go below 1.0 (in a span of about 150 data points). I want the function to return to me the number of times the values are above this threshold. I'm fairly new to R and am just confused on how to go about this. Any help is appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

If your data frame is called `df` then `sum(df$x>3)` will return the number of rows of `df` where `x` is greater than 3.

If there are missing values in `x` and you want to ignore them then use `sum(df$x>3, na.rm=TRUE)`.